# Will SaveChanges be Disposed if an Exception Occurs?

Tags: c#, exception, entity-framework-6

Kindly consider the following code:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    public IEmployeeRepository Employees { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Employees = new EmployeeRepository(_context);
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    try
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new Context()))
        {
            var employee = unitOfWork.Employees.GetById(1);
            employee.Name = "John";
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

            ComputeSalary(employee); 
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception logic goes here...
    }

    private void ComputeSalary(Employee employee)
    {
        int x = 1/0; // This will throw an exception.

        return;
    }
}
```

The `Context` class inherits from `DbContext` of Entity Framework. So in the **ComputeSalary()** function, you will see that an exception will be thrown since division of zero is not allowed. This will cause the code to exit the using block, thereby, disposing unitOfWork. My question is, will the changes performed by SaveChanges() still propagate to the database even though an exception occurred in the ComputeSalary() function?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically, what exactly does `SaveChanges()` and `ComputeSalary()` do? Where do you start and commit the transactions?

Comment: The `unitOfWork` *instance* will be disposed when the `using` block ends, regardless of *how*. What happens with the database is entirely up to the implementation of `UnitOfWork`, and how your database handles transactions. `UnitOfWork` is not a .NET Framework class, so that's hard to tell without context.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: SaveChanges() under unitOfWork is also DataContext.SaveChanges() in Entity Framework so this is where the transactions are committed. I just encapsulated the DataContext.SaveChanges() inside unitOfWork to decouple the application from a persistence framework. As an example, let's just say that inside ComputeSalary() we are performing other database transactions such as getting tax information, etc. I am assuming that since the update of the employee name has been committed prior to the exception, it means that it will be propagated to the database, right?

Comment: Please read the link I gave above and [edit] your question to improve your code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) or something like that, the changes will be committed.

PS: Not sure, but think if your using EF Core, it will commit to DataBase event if you have a TransactionScope. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5595